# Jackson Json object mapper - be able to parse Long numbers with "L" appeneded?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a configuration to allow Jackson to parse the following input?

```
{
    "a_big_id": 119034048687362500L,
    "hash_id": "92f90a0f862c4da7def6a",
    "object_id": "61"
}
```

Jackson can't parse the `L` at the end of the long - which is the input we have to work with. Any ideas on how to convert this to a valid JSON string?

I have other instances where `a_big_id` is type long (without the `L` suffix) and other times when `a_big_id` is a string ("aTextValue").

Thanks

Comment: why is even L appended ? don't tell me you make type decisions on the basis of that L

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot control the data that is being ingested. Is there any customization we can do to cleanse the data? @sikorski

Comment: @pl0u Jackson seems to follow the JSON syntax very strictly unlike Gson that can convert some non-well-formed JSON document values to strings to that the latter could be just parsed by a configured deserializer. I mean, I'm not sure if you can change the way how Jackson parses JSON streams.